# Update database after Stripe payment has completed successfully

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I've managed to set up a simple site with a payment form and the process works fine. I followed this tutorial: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/quickstart
So instead of just showing the success.html HTML page, I would like to store some data in the database, after the payment was completed and change the status of an order. I did have a look at Fulfillment, but I can't seem to understand how that can be integrated into the process. Can someone help me figure out how I might convert the success.html to success.php and do some database action?

Comment: I expect https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/custom-success-page will get you started. It shows how to retreieve the details from stripe after checkout. Once you've got those, you can write code to insert into your DB.

Comment: change the filename from `success.html` to `success.php` and do the same on the line `'success_url' => $YOUR_DOMAIN . '/success.html',` in `create-checkout-session.php`. Then you can rewrite the file as needed to store whatever data you want. If you need to use some data from one .php file within another, have a look at $_SESSION.

Answer (score 1):

Really you want to follow [the Fulfillment guide](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders) here as this uses Webhooks, which is the safest way to take action upon successful payment. Relying on success_url here is a bad idea because the browser could crash, client could disconnect, etc. Here's another page on [Webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) I recommend reading to get started.

Comment: Thanks @codename_duchess, but using the Fulfillment is exactly what is a bit unclear for me. I did try to figure out how to use that, but my question is how does this get triggered? So if I have a webhook with event listener on checkout.session.completed on https://example.com/success/, then if the browser crashes, then how is webhook triggered after payment is complete? :-)

Comment: Requests to your Webhook endpoint are made from Stripe's servers to your server. So once the payment is complete on Stripe's side, they would send a request to your Webhook endpoint with that event data in the payload.